# Transparency issues with overlayed, densely plotted graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm generating basic matplotlib line plots of cpu utilisation per core for multi-core servers. The line plots for each successive series of data are overlayed on top of each other, so the graph for the fist series to be plotted is often buried behind the others.

I've managed to improve the plot by progressively reducing the alpha for each series I'm plotting, but the problem is that often a later series is very 'busy'. The same line gets drawn repeatedly on the same pixels, so even with a low alpha it still obscures all the data behind it.

Ideally the colour and alpha for each line should be applied only once to each pixel, no matter how often that line actually goes through the pixel. I'd like to do is something like drawing each series on a separate 'layer', then apply the alpha to the whole layer in one go, so it doesn't mater how often a line is drawn on any given pixel. I hope that makes sense. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you get away with down-sampling or smoothing the 'busy' data set?  Can you get away with plotting the series shifted vertically from each other?  If your data is very dense, try plotting it as disconnected points (it might still look solid).

Comment: Does specifying `rasterized=True` to the `plot` call help at all?

Comment: Setting rasterized=True didn't make any difference, and it's not practical to re-sample the data. I tried setting lod=True as well, but no dice.